# IP Warmup Simple Approach question

Tags: marketing-cloud, ip-warming

Hello Marketing Cloud community,

Me and my team have an IP Warmup strategy to run this next week and there is a matter that I would like to get some insight from you:

Since we only have a total of around 100.000 contacts so we were thinking of using the IP Warmup Simple Approach defined in "IP Address Warming" Marketing Cloud Guide and in this trailhead (topic 7): https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/email-deliverability-concepts/warm-your-ip-address

Following this approach and this documentation, I understand that we can send up to 50.000 emails from day 1 to 7 per IP and per day.

But, our contactable database is mainly Gmail and Microsoft(around 63k and 30k respectively on a total of 98k) and the regular IP Warmup recommendations state that we should not send more than 5.000 in Gmail  and 20.000 for Microsoft for the first 3 days.

My questions are:

1. Does this regular IP warming recommendations apply to Simple Approach as well?
2. Is it possible to send 50.000 in first week/sends since the other recommendations (regular IP warming strategies) only recommend 20.000 daily sends until day 7?
3. Shouldn't we keep at least our first week sends to less than 5k for Gmails and 20K for Microsoft as the regular recommendation states?

Thank you in advance, I hope you can help me to better understand the main differences between these two kinds of IP Warmups.

Comment: To give you an idea, we also warmed an IP for ~100k list (we hired a third party to develop and warming plan). We sent ~15k emails in the first week. We spread this over 5 days of sending. The first day was a tiny volume (200 gmail, 200 microsoft, etc). We then ramped up each day. So your numbers seem potentially very high? The other factor is engagement - you should try to send to your most engaged subscribers first if possible. From experience, it's easier to warm a new IP than fix a burnt IP. So I would recommend getting some professional advice if you are not experienced with IP warming.

Comment: Thank you for your insight on this matter Ben! I will get back to my team with this new info and develop the best strategy possible. We will for sure have in consideration that our first sends are set too high in volume and re-organize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General note: If unsure, start slow.

General note #2: plan your sendout increases so they suit the slowest of your domains and adjust the others to the slow pace, not the opposite. Spoiler: in your case, Microsoft will dictate your plan, not gmail.

+Rushing through this won't help you in case you need time to allow for remediation strategies to happen without impact on major sendouts.
With microsoft, a need for remediation has been a common pattern for us. While your sendout volume is low, you can monitor, potentially wait out a support ticket to resolve an issue, and increase later. If you rush to pump out large numbers through an instable system and it fails, first you might burn your IP, but also a large sendout needlessly increases the opportunity cost / business impact of emails not sent. (Why bother sending a lot if say, 95% goes to spam anyway) >> It is in everyone's interest to work slowly.

on gmail:
While all of the above is true, gmail in particular has been a no-brainer, typically other domains dictate the plan, Gmail just rolls along.

We have regularly kicked off an IP Warming with 20k on gmail. We have then doubled weekly and never experienced problems. Sorry for anecdotal evidence, but we do IP warmings every couple months, so I feel fairly confident that this is *currently* correct. With my general note #2 in mind, it doesn't really matter how high you can go. No need to trust my anecdotes, feel free to start gmail at 5000, you will probably anyway devise your plan based on your slower domain:

on microsoft:
register your domain at SNDS https://sendersupport.olc.protection.outlook.com/snds/
to get a green / yellow / red kind of status update on what microsoft thinks of you as a sender on a daily basis.

We typically start off with 1500 addresses on microsoft, with plans to double weekly, or, if we can go for 4-7 mails per week, we double twice per week. This number is rather arbitrary, but again - it doesn't really matter "how high we can go" -

We typically see "red status" on SNDS right off the bat, which won't auto-resolve. It corresponds with suspiciously low opening & low click rates & mails that get delivered to the spam folder on some of our own microsoft inboxes we include. The solution is to enter a support ticket w. SF deliverability who resolve this with Microsoft. The support ticket typically takes a few days, during which we keep to our slow plan (as rates are anyway not great), and within <10 business days or so, we are "green". In this timeframe, it is pointless to cram as much volume onto your new IP as possible.

There also is a thing called Preemptive Accomodation where you can apparently alleviate this in advance though microsoft support.
https://help.returnpath.com/hc/en-us/articles/360003828271-How-to-use-Microsoft-s-Preemptive-Accommodation-process-for-IP-Warm-Ups

As our approach above has predictably worked for us this far, I have not tried that. But returnpath should know what they are talking about here and it might open the door for speeding up microsoft, and gmail can start reasonably fast anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your insight on this matter Jonas! I will get back to my team with this new info and develop the best strategy possible. Microsoft will be our priority and will increase our 3 weekly sends slowly and progressively according to the numbers you mentioned.